# Suggestion please, How to include test data extension while sending from journey

Tags: ampscript, journeybuilder

I'm looking out for your suggestion or concept to work on this task.
Is it possible to include contacts of specified data extension to target data extension using AMPscript and send them emails to both DE contacts?

I'm thinking of this situation because I'm sending from a journey builder so I can't use two data extensions as entry sources.
I don't have the right to update the entry source data extension through the query because it's our main data extension.

Is there any way that I can achieve this using AMPscript?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar scenario in needing to add a seed data extension so internal staff members are added to a journey. The easiest way to address this is by writing a SQL query with a union to join the two datasets into one new data extension.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I guess what you have suggested is the best solution. I will upvote your answer once I reach 15 reputations :)